# How can 2 or more pie-charts with the property of "pullOutOnlyOne" work with one another- Amcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, pie-chart, amcharts

There are two pie-charts. I want the functionality so that only one slice of the pie-charts pulls out whichever last clicked. "pullOutOnlyOne" is working only for single pie-chart. I need it to be worked like this, If i click on a slice of One pie-chart then second one, then slice of first pie-chart should pulled in.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/6oo9jvLj/)

I tried this one but unable to capture which pie-chart and which slice...:(

`var lastClickedSlice;
...
...
{
     "event": "clickSlice",
     "method": function (e) {
           if (lastClickedSlice === "") {
                 lastClickedSlice = e.dataItem.dataContext;
           } else {
                 console.log(JSON.stringify(lastClickedSlice));
                 lastClickedSlice.clickSlice(lastClickedSlice.index);
                 lastClickedSlice = e.dataItem.dataContext;
           }
   }
}`

How to implement this thing with 2 or more than 2 pie-charts?

Answer (score 0):

Add click listners on each slice of the chart, for example on chart-1 slice click event below :

`"listeners": [{
    "event": "clickSlice",
    "method": function(e) {

      chart2.pullOutRadius = "0%";
      chart2.validateData();
      chart2.pullOutRadius = "20%";
      chart2.validateData();
    }
    }]`

Working Demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/6oo9jvLj/5/

Comment: using validateData(), if there are few pie-charts, what if there are more than 10 pie-charts?

Comment: store it in an array